Is Time Complexity related to change in Kolmogorov Complexity?
Let $M$ be a Turing machine which computes a total recursive function. We will use the notation $M(x)$ to denote not just the output string but the entire instantaneous description of $M$ after halting on $x$. Let $A(s)$ represent the plain Kolmogorov complexity of $s$. Let $T(M, x)$ be the number of steps it takes for $M$ to halt on input $x$.
Main question
Is it true that
\begin{align*}
 2^{A(M(x))} - 2^{A(M(x - 1))} &\preccurlyeq
 T(M, x)
\end{align*}
And when $M$ is bijective
\begin{align*}
 2^{A(M(x))} - 2^{A(M(x - 1))} &\asymp
 T(M, x)
\end{align*}
Also looking for any references on results related to the relationship between computational complexity (time/space) and Kolmogorov complexity.
The derivation(?)
Let $\phi_M(t, x)$ represent an encoding of the instantaneous description of $M$ on input $x$ after $t$ steps (by instantaneous description, I mean the head position, state, and tape string).
Define the function $\Phi_M(t)$ via
$$\begin{align*}  \iota(t) &= \max_x\left(\sum_{n=0}^x T(M, n) < t\right) \\
\Phi_M(t) &= \phi_M(t - T(M, \iota(t)), \iota(t)) \end{align*}$$
This is essentially meant to be a sequence of all the instantaneous descriptions of $M$ in order of time and input, indexed by $t$.
Denote $A(s)$ to mean the standard Kolmogorov complexity of $s$.
We now apply the axiomatic definition of plain Kolmogorov complexity to find
$$\begin{align*}
    A(\Phi_M(t)) &\leq A(t) + c_{\Phi_M} \\
    A(\Phi_M(t)) &\leq |t| + c_{\Phi_M} \\
\end{align*}$$
Now, setting $t = \sum_{n=0}^x T(M, x)$ yields
\begin{align*}
    A(\Phi_M(\sum_{n=0}^x T(M, n))) &\leq |\sum_{n=0}^x T(M, n)| + O(1) + c_{\Phi_M} \\
\end{align*}
But $\Phi_M(\sum_{n=0}^x T(M, n))$ is just $M(x)$, so
\begin{align*}
    A(M(x)) &\leq |\sum_{n=0}^x T(M, n)| + O(1) + c_{\Phi_M} \\
    A(M(x)) &\leq \log(\sum_{n=0}^x T(M, n)) + O(1) + c_{\Phi_M} \\
    2^{A(M(x))} &\leq c'_{\Phi_M}\sum_{n=0}^x T(M, n) \\
\end{align*}
But then, taking the discrete derivative yields
\begin{align*}
 2^{A(M(x))} - 2^{A(M(x - 1))} &\preccurlyeq T(M, x)
\end{align*}
Thus a Turing machine's time complexity is asymptotically bounded below by the change in Kolmogorov complexity between outputs.
This already feels a bit 'too good to be true', but we can push it further. Note that if $M$ is bijective, then $\Phi_M$ must also be bijective, for if there were any repeated instantaneous descriptions of $M$, then $M$ would either have a repeated output on some input, or go into an infinite loop which contradicts it being total recursive.
So if $M$ is bijective, does this imply that $A(\Phi_M(t)) \sim |t|$?
In which case, we yield
\begin{align*}
 2^{A(M(x))} - 2^{A(M(x - 1))} &\asymp T(M, x)
\end{align*}
And thus, any Turing machine's time complexity is completely asymptotically characterized by the change in Kolmogorov complexity, since from any Turing machine $M(x)$ we can form a bijective Turing machine $M'(x)$ such that $$M'(x) = (M(t) : t \leq x)$$ (i.e. the string of all outputs of $M$ up to and including $x$)
Again, this feels almost 'too good to be true' as I have not been able to find this result anywhere. So I feel like there may be something fundamentally wrong with this proof even though I cannot see what it is.
So my question is, is there anything wrong with this proof? If not, where can I find more information about this result and results like it?
Why the proof may be incorrect
I would also like to add a note about why, at least the second asymptotic equation, seems almost too good to be true, and yet doesn't seem to break anything. It would seem that one can arbitrarily increase the run time complexity of an algorithm without actually changing its output, but we denoted the output to include the entire instantaneous description of $M$. But this would suggest that it may be impossible to arbitrarily increase the running time in a way that actually increases its asymptotic complexity without adding substantial information to the output description of the machine. Is that true? It feels like it can't be true.
The step of switching to asymptotic equality is also obviously shaky, but the justification for this is that in the bijective case would seem to suggest that the pigeonhole principle could find a separate encoding that encoded the description of the outputs of $\Phi_M$ in asymptotically close to $|t|$ bits. Since we are dealing with plain complexity here, then this would mean that the other encoding is merely a constant away.
The first asymptotic inequality seems too good to be true because the argument works in the non-bijective case without even requiring $M$ to output the instantaneous description. In that case it seems to work even if we just restrict ourselves to the tape output.
In addition, I have searched for a few months and have not found this result, or even this general line of thinking, anywhere. Perhaps most notably absent in the text 'Introduction to Kolmogorov Complexity and Its applications', and searching the literature has not yielded anything that looks like this as far as I can tell.

@user3716267 Isn't a sequence of elements in $A$, $(a_i)$ with  $i \in I$  (in other words a sequence indexed by $i$) just a function from $I$ to $A$? In which case what I mean is we set the index to specific input values. $\Phi_M(t)$ is just a total recursive function. $A(\Phi_M(t))$ is just the kolmogorov complexity of the output of $\Phi_M$ on input $t$.

Please don't use "Edit:" and append more stuff.  Instead, revise the question so it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time, and presents all material in a logical order.  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/755 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127639/160917.

I would say that since this post doesn't have many comments or any answers, revising the question may be appropriate. Else, revising a question to make it complete for a new reader will lead to some unpleasantness in general, as the exisitng comments and answers may look out of place (in which case, I like the "edit 1/2/3..." approach

Thank you, I have edited the question to remove 'Edit 1/ 2/ 3 etc'

There is a site for computer science: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/  Since nobody seems to care about this question here, maybe that site would be more appropriate for this type of question.

You've lost me at $x-1$. How do you subtract $1$ from a string of input characters?

@LeeMosher Good question.
Here, for inputs and outputs of all total recursive functions, I am implicitly assuming the standard representation of the natural numbers where the bit string $b_n\dots b_1b_0$ represents $\sum_i b_i 2^i$. Then $x - 1$ is just shorthand for any algorithm that subtracts one and outputs the corresponding bit string. AFAIK, the choice of algorithm doesn't matter, and one can assume this encoding without loss of generality since the natural numbers are one to one with any input string.

But really, I don't think the encoding matters, so long as the input strings are one to one with the natural numbers, and it is consistent across all of the recursive functions involved. But this is indeed one of the many 'tricky' bits about this proof.
As far as I know, this is still completely formal, and it seems somewhat simple enough, but there are many very non-intuitive aspects of the proof itself and the final result when you think about it too long.
